# Moderation / Submission Settings of Youtube Direct

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have been trying to change the Submission Mode to NEW but it still on NEW OR EXISTING even after clicking on Save Changes button. I don't want users to submit existing videos and the "Submit an Existing Video" button should not be there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There's an unfortunate bug in the way that YouTube Direct uses Guice that causes the configuration object to get cached and reused as long as the JVM that is running YouTube Direct remains active. In practice, this normally means that the new settings will take effect after a couple of hours.

In general, our focus is on YouTube Direct Lite right now. If you'd like to learn more, please see

http://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/

You can customize the JavaScript code directly to not display the Existing Video tab in YouTube Direct Lite.